# Colour Scatterplot based on decision tree route

Tags: r, scatter-plot, decision-tree

I am using a data set about seeds that contains the headers [class , area, perimeter, compactness, length, Width Asymmetry, GrooveLength]

this is a classification exercise and I have a decision tree that looks like

[image: Decision tree for the seed data]

I have selected the two variables GrooveLength and Asymmetry, to plot on a scatter graph, which plots the whole tables points against each other,

[image: Scatter Plot of GrooverLength/Asymmetry]

my question is how do I colour code the points according to the decision
tree output?

the plot is by using simply `twopoints <- seedfull[,c(8,7)] plot(twopoints)`

Comment: To be clear: is your question about **(1)** how to capture in your dataset the route taken by each observation; or **(2)** how to map that route attribute to the graphical color?

Comment: @Greg to confirm, I need to do both

Comment: Well, assuming you can capture the route as an attribute in your dataset, mapping it to a color should be pretty straightforward.  Just apply the Grammar of Graphics as implemented in **`ggplot2`**, with the `Route` attribute mapped to `color`: `aes(x = GrooveLength, y = Asymmetry, color = Route)`.  DataCamp has a nice example [here](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-data-visualization-with-ggplot2/aesthetics?ex=14).

Comment: Also, could you provide a reproducible sample of your dataset?  Try pasting the output of `dput(head(your_seeds_data, 50))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer: including `col = seeddata$class)` to the plot